# Is it safe to feed unaligned buffers to MTLBuffer?

Tags: ios, memory-management, shared-memory, metal

When trying to use Metal to rapidly draw pixel buffers to the screen from memory, we create `MTLBuffer` objects using `MTLDevice.makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy:..)` to allow the GPU to directly read the pixels from memory without having to copy it. Shared memory is really a must-have for achieving good pixel transfer performance.

The catch is that `makeBuffer` requires a page-aligned memory address and a page aligned `length`. Those requirements are not only in the documentation -- they are also enforced using runtime assertions.

The code I am writing has to deal with a variety of incoming resolutions and pixel formats, and occasionally I get unaligned buffers or unaligned lengths. After researching this I discovered a hack that allows me to use shared memory for those instances.

Basically what I do is I round the unaligned buffer address down to the nearest page boundary, and use the `offset` parameter from `makeTexture` to ensure that the GPU starts reading from the right place. Then I round up `length` to the nearest page size. Obviously that memory is going to be valid (because allocations can only occur on page boundaries), and I think it's safe to assume the GPU isn't writing to or corrupting that memory.

Here is the code I'm using to allocate shared buffers from unaligned buffers:

```
extension MTLDevice {
    func makeTextureFromUnalignedBuffer(textureDescriptor : MTLTextureDescriptor, bufferPtr : UnsafeMutableRawPointer, bufferLength : UInt, bytesPerRow : Int) -> MTLTexture? {

        var calculatedBufferLength = bufferLength
        let pageSize = UInt(getpagesize())
        let pageSizeBitmask = UInt(getpagesize()) - 1

        let alignedBufferAddr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(bitPattern: UInt(bitPattern: bufferPtr) & ~pageSizeBitmask)
        let offset = UInt(bitPattern: bufferPtr) & pageSizeBitmask

        assert(bytesPerRow % 64 == 0 && offset % 64 == 0, "Supplied bufferPtr and bytesPerRow must be aligned on a 64-byte boundary!")

        calculatedBufferLength += offset

        if (calculatedBufferLength & pageSizeBitmask) != 0 {
            calculatedBufferLength &= ~(pageSize - 1)
            calculatedBufferLength += pageSize
        }

        let buffer = self.makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy: alignedBufferAddr!, length: Int(calculatedBufferLength), options: .storageModeShared, deallocator: nil)
        return buffer.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor, offset: Int(offset), bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow)
    }
}
```

I've tested this on numerous different buffers and it seems to work perfectly (only tested on iOS, not on macOS). **My question is: Is this approach safe? Any obvious reasons why this wouldn't work?**

Then again, if it is safe, why were the requirements imposed in the first place? Why isn't the API just doing this for us?

Comment: I would also ask this question on the apple developer forums.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have submitted an Apple TSI (Technical Support Incident) for this question, and the answer is basically **yes, it is safe**. Here is the exact response in case anyone is interested:

> After discussing your approach with engineering we concluded that it
>   was valid and safe.  Some noteworthy quotes:
>
> “The framework shouldn’t care about the fact that the user doesn’t own
>   the entire page, because it shouldn’t ever read before the offset
>   where the valid data begins.”
>
> “It really shouldn’t [care], but in general if the developer can use
>   page-allocators rather than malloc for their incoming images, that
>   would be nice.”
>
> As to why the alignment constraints/assertions are in place:
>
> “Typically mapping memory you don’t own into another address space is
>   a bit icky, even if it works in practice.  This is one reason why we
>   required mapping to be page aligned, because the hardware really is
>   mapping (and gaining write access) to the entire page.”

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks!